# Devise 3.2.4 "Forgot my password" link using the update method in devise/passwords controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Hi guys,
I'm using the devise source of github and Rails 4.1.4.

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'devise', path: '../devise'
```

and my devise passwords/new.html.erb view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), method: :put) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.button :submit, t('.send_me_reset_password_instructions'
   , :default => "Send me reset password instructions")
   , class: 'btn-primary pull-right', method: "post" %>    
<% end %>
```

I puth method: "post" to try it to force create method

My config/routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: 
{ omniauth_callbacks: "users/omniauth_callbacks" }, skip: :registrations

devise_scope :user do
  resource :registration,
         only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update],
         path: 'users',
         path_names: { new: 'sign_up' },
         controller: 'devise/registrations',
         as: :user_registration
end
```

My devise routes:

```
      user_password POST     /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
  new_user_password GET      /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
 edit_user_password GET      /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
```

Devise generated html form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/password" class="simple_form new_user" id="new_user" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
.....
</form>
```

But, when I hit the submit button, I am sent to the update(PUT) method in the controller. And I think, that I will need to be redirected to the create(POST) method.

```
Started PUT "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-25 12:07:05 -0300
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"gYiLxMKPSvCN5x6n5b0TtNyzTPcH1L3825Jp7NAdzs0=", "user"=>  {"email"=>"duduribeiro.gba@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Enviar instruções para redefinição da senha"}
gem install awesome_print  # <-- highly recommended

From: /home/carlos.ribeiro/code/devise/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb @ line 32 Devise::PasswordsController#update:

   31: def update
=> 32:   binding.pry
   33:   self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)
   34:   yield resource if block_given?
   35: 
   36:   if resource.errors.empty?
   37:     resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
   38:     flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated :    :updated_not_active
   39:     set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_flashing_format?
   40:     sign_in(resource_name, resource)
   41:     respond_with resource, location: after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
   42:   else
   43:     respond_with resource
   44:   end
   45: end
```

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `method: "post"` from your submit button. Instead set the HTTP method as an attribute of the form via `html: { method: :post }`. Your implementation uses `method: :put` in devise passwords/new.html.erb. Here's the default example from Devise:

```
<h2>Forgot your password?</h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Send me reset password instructions" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Comment: Because is the create method that send to uset the instructions to reset the password:
`def create
    binding.pry
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(resource_params)
    yield resource if block_given?

    if successfully_sent?(resource)
      respond_with({}, location: after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name))
    else
      respond_with(resource)
    end
  end`

Comment: The right flow is the PUT method? When I enter in the forgot my password page, I enter my email in the field and submit? thanks

Comment: I downloaded the https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise, and debugged. The right flow is to call #create

Comment: I guess you're overriding your Devise password controller. Could you add it to your question along with an explanation of why you need to override it instead of using the default?

Comment: I'm not overriding =/.. I'm using the default... I just put a breakpoint to it... (i forked the devise source)
thanks

Comment: When i submit the form with my email, to generate a new reset password email. ( http://prntscr.com/469lq3 )... it calls the #update method from devise/password controller, when the correct flow, is to call #create. ( http://prntscr.com/469m5t )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58015/discussion-between-sergio-lopez-mendez-and-carlos-ribeiro).